# How to re-use the return values of matplotlib.Axes.hist?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Suppose I want to plot a histogram of the same data twice:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax1,ax2 = fig.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=1)
ax1.hist(foo)
ax2.hist(foo)
ax2.set_yscale("log")
ax2.set_xlabel("foo")
fig.show()
```

Note that I call [`Axes.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist.html) **twice**, and it could be expensive. I wonder if there is an *easy* way to re-use the return value of the 1st call to make the second one cheap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [`ax.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist.html) docs, there is a related example of reusing [`np.histogram`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html#numpy.histogram) output:

> The **`weights`** parameter can be used to draw a histogram of data that has already been binned by treating each bin as a single point with a weight equal to its count.
>
> ```py
> counts, bins = np.histogram(data)
> plt.hist(bins[:-1], bins, weights=counts)
> ```

We can use the same approach with [`ax.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist.html) since it also returns counts and bins (along with a bar container):

```py
x = np.random.default_rng(123).integers(10, size=100)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 3))

counts, bins, bars = ax1.hist(x)          # original hist
ax2.hist(bins[:-1], bins, weights=counts) # rebuilt via weights params
```

[image: rebuilt via weights param]

---

Alternatively, reconstruct the original histogram using [`ax.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html) and restyle the width/alignment to match [`ax.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist.html):

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 3))

counts, bins, bars = ax1.hist(x)                    # original hist
ax2.bar(bins[:-1], counts, width=1.0, align='edge') # rebuilt via ax.bar
```

[image: rebuilt via ax.bar]