# Probability of a roll dice

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I generated 1,000,000 random number draws using the random module

```
import random
liste = []
for i in range(0, 1000000):
liste.append(random.uniform(0,1))
```

Now I have to store the values obtained in a histogram at 6 bins using the bins option.
And using if/else conditions on the list items, write a algorithm to simulate the result of 1,000,000 dice rolls.
Then I have to calculate the frequency of occurrence of each value and compare it to the expected probability p = 1/6.

Does anyone know how to do this please I have no idea...

Thanks in advance!

edit: concerning the bins options

they talk about this :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# Création de la figure et des axes
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1, sharey=True, tight_layout=True)
# Ajout de l'histogramme
axs.hist(valeurs, bins=np.arange(0.5, 7.5, 1), ec="black")
axs.set_title("Résultats jet dé")
axs.set_xlabel("Valeur dé")
```

[image: gives me this]

After using @Roland_Smith's program it gives me this

```
 #import random
 #liste = []
 #for i in range(0, 1000000):
 #    liste.append(random.uniform(0,1))
 import random
 liste = random.choices((1,2,3,4,5,6), k=1000000)
 import collections
 c = collections.Counter(liste)
 print(c)

 p = [j/1e6 for j in c.values()]
 print(p)

 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np
 # Création de la figure et des axes
 fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1, sharey=True, tight_layout=True)
 # Ajout de l'histogramme
 axs.hist(c, bins=np.arange(0.5, 7.5, 1), ec="black")
 axs.set_title("Résultats jet dé")
 axs.set_xlabel("Valeur dé")
```

but the problem is that my histogram looks like this
[image]

is it normal because each number has the same probability of appearing or is it not normal?

edit for tdy

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# Création de la figure et des axes
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1, sharey=True, tight_layout=True)
# Ajout de l'histogramme
axs.hist(c,ec="black")
axs.set_title("Résultats jet dé")
axs.set_xlabel("Valeur dé")
```

[image]

edit after help for @JohanC

```
#import random
#liste = []
#for i in range(0, 1000000):
#    liste.append(random.uniform(0,1))
import random
liste = random.choices((1,2,3,4,5,6), k=1000000)
import collections
c = collections.Counter(liste)
print(c)

p = [j/1e6 for j in c.values()]
print(p)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.bar(c.keys(), c.values())

# Création de la figure et des axes
#fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1, sharey=True, tight_layout=True)
# Ajout de l'histogramme
#axs.hist(c,ec="black")
#axs.set_title("Résultats jet dé")
#axs.set_xlabel("Valeur dé")
```

[image]

i get a value of 160000 for each dice face, i.e. 6. but 6*160000+960000 i shouldn't get the number of rolls, i.e. 1000000?

Comment: "*histogram at 6 bins using the bins option*" What is the "*bins option*"? What is "*histogram*" is this context? Are you maybe using `r`?

Comment: i uptaded my code, you can see about what they mentionned with "option bins"... thanks for your help :)

Comment: [`Axes.hist` returns the values, bins, and bars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70949207/13138364) so you can do: `counts, bins, bars = axs.hist(valeurs, bins=np.arange(0.5, 7.5, 1), ec="black")`

Comment: @JonSg like this : axs.hist(c,bins=np.arange(0.5, 7.5, 1),ec="black") ?

Comment: @tdy I want the plot! but how to put the new values obtained with counter values in this histogram?

Comment: You mean how to label the histogram's bars? Use the `bar_label` method (requires matplotlib version 3.4.0+). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71095250/13138364

Comment: @tdy look I updated my topic, you can see what my problem is with the histogram... :(

Comment: You shouldn't mix `Counter` with `hist`. They both count+bin the data. If you use `Counter`, just plot it with a regular `bar` plot. If you use the raw data, plot with `hist`.

Comment: @tdy I'm not sure I understand, I still have a problem with the display of bars, I updated the topic...

Comment: "i get a value of 160000 for each dice face, i.e. 6. but 6*160000+960000 i shouldn't get the number of rolls, i.e. 1000000?" No, the bars are a little higher than the 160000 tick, as they should be. They will not be the exact same values, either, because of the randomness, but they will be close enough that you might not see the difference on a plot like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dice rolls produce an integer value.

So using `random.uniform` (which returns a `float`) is not the right way.

Try:

```
import random
liste = random.choices((1,2,3,4,5,6), k=1000000)
```

Then, I'd use `collections.Counter` to count the values:

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter(liste)
print(c)
```

This would get you something like:

```
Counter({6: 167399, 5: 167083, 2: 166789, 3: 166548, 1: 166236, 4: 165945})
```

Calculating the probability:

```
p = [j/1e6 for j in c.values()]
```

This yields:

```
[0.167083, 0.165945, 0.167399, 0.166789, 0.166548, 0.166236]
```

For plotting;

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar(c.keys(),p)
plt.show()
```

It will look something like this:

[image: plot of dice probability]

The reason that all bars look about the same is because they *are*.

Let's check the difference between `p` and the probability of a fair dice, which is 1/6:

```
[round(j-1/6, 6) for j in p]
```

This gives:

```
[0.000416, -0.000722, 0.000732, 0.000122, -0.000119, -0.000431]
```

So the actual counted probability is pretty close to that of a fair dice.

Comment: thank you for your help, it is very valuable...how do I store the values obtained in a 6-bin histogram using the bins option?

Comment: The `Counter` basically *is* a 6-bin histogram. :-)

Comment: @AspiringPhysicist What does "*histogram using the bins option*" mean? Are you referencing something like `pandas.cut()` or something in `r`?

Comment: can i plot it with a list like list=[1,2,3,4,5,6];plt.plot(list,Counter)?

Comment: Is that `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()`? Pretend that we don't have any clue or context about what you are attempting to do.

Comment: i updated my subject you can see what they talk about @JonSG

Comment: @AspiringPhysicist  You can plot via `plt.bar(c.keys(), c.values())`.

Comment: @JohanC when i plot it, i get a value of 160000 for each dice face, i.e. 6. but 6*160000+960000 i shouldn't get the number of rolls, i.e. 1000000? u updated the topic with plot

Comment: @AspiringPhysicist See updated answer.

Comment: @AspiringPhysicist You can do `plt.ylim(min(p) * 0.99, max(p) * 1.01)` (or `plt.ylim(min(c.values()) * 0.99, max(c.values()) * 1.01)` if working with the counters instead of the probabilities) to only see the tops of the bars.  The counters will be around `1666677`.

Comment: merci beaucoup @JohanC

Comment: @RolandSmith thank you for having solved most of my problem, you have been a great help to me, as well as all the people who have answered this post, merci beaucoup!!! :))